# How to disable logging errors generated by API kit router in console?

Tags: mule, raml, mule-esb, apikit

Is there a possiblity to disable the errors generated by RAML validation in console by APIkit router. In case of RAML validations such as 400 bad request, I need to generate the error by these errors should not be logged in console. In case of Choice Exception strategy there is a attribute LogException but in case of globalExceptionMapping I could not find it.

Thanks

Sushma

Answer (score 0):

On Mule 3.8 (maybe earlier), the `mapping-exception-strategy` have a property `enableNotifications`. Such as:

```
<apikit:mapping-exception-strategy name="api-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping" enableNotifications="false">
```

Comment: I tried that property, but still I can see the msgs in the console.

Comment: Can you post your entire flow? What version of Mule are you using? Maybe the catching exception strategy logs the error before handing the exception to the mapping-exception-strategy.